# Add a Watermark on Video after merging Video and Audio Asset into one in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avfoundation, avasset

I am working on `Video` based application in `Swift3`. As per my requirement  I have to merge `Video` and `Audio` `AVAsset` into one, adjust their volumes separately and save the final `Video` in `iPhone Device gallery`. This is working fine using below code:

```
func mergeVideoAndMusicWithVolume(assetVideo: AVAsset, assetMusic: AVAsset, startAudioTime: Float64, volumeVideo: Float, volumeAudio: Float){

        //To merging a video and a music and set it a volume
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as String

        let composition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        let compositionVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let compositionAudioVideo: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let compositionAudioMusic: AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

        //Add video to the final record
        do {
            try compositionVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetVideo.duration), of: assetVideo.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0], at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
        }

        //Extract audio from the video and the music
        let audioMix: AVMutableAudioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
        var audioMixParam: [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters] = []

        let assetVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = assetVideo.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
        let assetMusicTrack: AVAssetTrack = assetMusic.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

        let videoParam: AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: assetVideoTrack)
        videoParam.trackID = compositionAudioVideo.trackID

        let musicParam: AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: assetMusicTrack)
        musicParam.trackID = compositionAudioMusic.trackID


        //Set final volume of the audio record and the music
        videoParam.setVolume(volumeVideo, at: kCMTimeZero)
        musicParam.setVolume(volumeAudio, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //Add setting
        audioMixParam.append(musicParam)
        audioMixParam.append(videoParam)

        //Add audio on final record
        //First: the audio of the record and Second: the music
        do {
            try compositionAudioVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetVideo.duration), of: assetVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
            assertionFailure()
        }

        do {
            try compositionAudioMusic.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(Int64(startAudioTime * 10000), 10000), assetVideo.duration), of: assetMusicTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
            assertionFailure()
        }

        //Add parameter
        audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixParam

        //Remove the previous temp video if exist
        let filemgr = FileManager.default
        do {
            if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: "\(docsDir)/movie-merge-music.mov") {
                try filemgr.removeItem(atPath: "\(docsDir)/movie-merge-music.mov")
            } else {
            }
        } catch _ {
        }

        //Exporte the final record’
        let completeMovie = "\(docsDir)/movie-merge-music.mov"
        let completeMovieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: completeMovie)
        let exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        exporter.outputURL = completeMovieUrl as URL
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter.audioMix = audioMix

        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { _ in
                self.exportDidFinish(exporter)
            }
        })
    }


    func exportDidFinish(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {
        if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
            let outputURL = session.outputURL

            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Problem: Now I have to add a `Watermark` image on final `Video` before saving to `Device gallery`.

I checked [Swift 3: How to add watermark on video ? AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool iOS 10 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530367/swift-3-how-to-add-watermark-on-video-avvideocompositioncoreanimationtool-ios) but after applying Watermark, Video is coming in small area of frame size.

Note: Here is my class which I am using to add Watermark:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation
import Photos

enum QUWatermarkPosition {
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
    case Default
}

class VideoWatermarkManager: NSObject {

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: nil, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : QUWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            let clipVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
            do {
                try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize

            let parentLayer = CALayer()
            let videoLayer = CALayer()
            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)


                let watermarkImage = UIImage(named: name)
                let imageLayer = CALayer()
                imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.cgImage

                var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                let imageSize : CGFloat = 57.0

                switch (position) {
                case .TopLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .TopRight:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .BottomLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                case .BottomRight, .Default:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                }


                imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                imageLayer.opacity = 0.85
                parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)


            let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            videoComp.renderScale = 1.0
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
            _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack

            let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]

            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mov")

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter?.outputURL = url
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp

            exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                        if flag {
                            // Save to library
                            //                            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

                            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                                }) { saved, error in
                                    if saved {
                                        completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            //                            if library.videoAtPathIs(compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum: outputURL) {
                            //                                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL,
                            //                                                                           completionBlock: { (assetURL:NSURL!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                            //
                            //                                                                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, exporter, outputURL)
                            //                                })
                            //                            }
                        } else {
                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                     at: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
                concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }

        return instruction
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I add the `Watermark` on my `Video`?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to add the watermark? This seems to be the critical part that's missing here. My guess is that you don't specify the ExportSession size preset (you're using "Highest Quality" - try instead avassetexportpreset1280x720) and the final video size is using the Watermark as the size, not the underlying video layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response @TimBull, I have updated my question. Please have a look..

Comment: Actually my requirement is I have to merge multiple videos into one video. If it is not possible to add Watermark for Final video. So, Is it possible to add Watermark image for each Video (AVAsset) separately? If yes then can you help me on this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on a project and used this code. Maybe this will help you to add watermark.

```
import UIKit
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation
import Photos
import SpriteKit

enum PDWatermarkPosition {
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
    case Default
}

class PDVideoWaterMarker: NSObject {


    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, watermarkText text : String , saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSessionStatus?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))


            if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).count == 0

            {
                completion!(nil, nil, nil)
                return
            }

               let clipVideoTrack =  videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

                self.addAudioTrack(composition: mixComposition, videoAsset: videoAsset as! AVURLAsset)


            do {
                try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize //CGSize(width: 375, height: 300)

            print("videoSize--\(videoSize)")
            let parentLayer = CALayer()

            let videoLayer = CALayer()

            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            //videoLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

            if name != nil {
                let watermarkImage = UIImage(named: name)
                let imageLayer = CALayer()
                //imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
                imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.cgImage

                var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                let imageSize : CGFloat = 57.0

                switch (position) {
                case .TopLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = 0
                    break
                case .TopRight:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize - 30
                    yPosition = 30
                    break
                case .BottomLeft:
                    xPosition = 0
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                case .BottomRight, .Default:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                }


                imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                imageLayer.opacity = 0.65
                parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)



                if text != nil {
                    let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
                    titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                    titleLayer.string = text
                    titleLayer.font = "Helvetica" as CFTypeRef
                    titleLayer.fontSize = 20
                    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentRight
                    titleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition - imageSize, width: videoSize.width - imageSize/2 - 4, height: 57)
                    titleLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
                }
            }

            let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)


            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mixComposition.duration)
            instruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack

            let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack, asset: videoAsset)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]



            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())


            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(date).mov")

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter?.outputURL = url
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
            exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp


            exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                        if flag {                            
                            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                                }) { saved, error in
                                    if saved {
                                        completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            completion!(AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addAudioTrack(composition: AVMutableComposition, videoAsset: AVURLAsset) {
        let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
        let audioTracks = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
        for audioTrack in audioTracks {
            try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }
    }


    private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }

        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 375
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                     at: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let yFix = 375 + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: CGFloat(yFix))
                concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, at: kCMTimeZero)

        }

        return instruction
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited question. I think I am also using the same class :(

Comment: Yes they are same class with some extra modification. But is this not working for you ??

Comment: I tried but getting error: Type 'UIColor' has no member 'prospectDugoutVideoBackgroundColor'

Comment: Can you look into this @RahulSinghaRoyhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419495/fade-effect-is-not-working-between-videos-while-merging-in-swift3-ios Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate it you have done lots of work, But actually its not working for portrait videos.

Answer (score 2):

With a dynamic size for the different devices. video will not get cropped in height and width. it will work with 100% result
*I used the same code with some of my code modifications. Enjoy

```
enum PDWatermarkPosition {
    case TopLeft
    case TopRight
    case BottomLeft
    case BottomRight
    case Default
}
class MediaWatermark: NSObject {
    
    
    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSession.Status?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: nil, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, imageName name : String, watermarkText text : String , saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSession.Status?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        self.watermark(video: videoAsset, watermarkText: text, imageName: name, saveToLibrary: flag, watermarkPosition: position) { (status, session, outputURL) -> () in
            completion!(status, session, outputURL)
        }
    }

    private func watermark(video videoAsset:AVAsset, watermarkText text : String!, imageName name : String!, saveToLibrary flag : Bool, watermarkPosition position : PDWatermarkPosition, completion : ((_ status : AVAssetExportSession.Status?, _ session: AVAssetExportSession?, _ outputURL : URL?) -> ())?) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {

            let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

            let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))


            if videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).count == 0

            {
                completion!(nil, nil, nil)
                return
            }

            let clipVideoTrack =  videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

                self.addAudioTrack(composition: mixComposition, videoAsset: videoAsset as! AVURLAsset)


            do {
                try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: videoAsset.duration), of: clipVideoTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

    
            let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize //CGSize(width: 375, height: 300)
            
            

            print("videoSize--\(videoSize)")
            let parentLayer = CALayer()

            let videoLayer = CALayer()

            parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
            //videoLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)

            if name != nil {
                let watermarkImage = UIImage(named: "mediaMarkLight")
                let imageLayer = CALayer()
                //imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
                imageLayer.contents = watermarkImage?.cgImage

                var xPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                var yPosition : CGFloat = 0.0
                let imageSize : CGFloat = 200

                switch (position) {
                case .TopLeft:
                    xPosition = 30
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - (200 + 30)
                    break
                case .TopRight:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - 200 - 30
                    yPosition = 30
                    break
                case .BottomLeft:
                    xPosition = 30
                    yPosition = 30 // videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                case .BottomRight, .Default:
                    xPosition = videoSize.width - imageSize
                    yPosition = videoSize.height - imageSize
                    break
                }


                imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: yPosition, width: 200, height: 65)
                imageLayer.opacity = 1.0

                parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)



                if text != nil {
                    let titleLayer = CATextLayer()
                    titleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                    titleLayer.string = ""
                    titleLayer.font = Constant.FONT_Mulli_EXTRABOLD as CFTypeRef
                    titleLayer.fontSize = 16
                    titleLayer.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left
                    titleLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition - 20, y: yPosition - 55 , width: videoSize.width - 200/2 - 4, height: 57)
                    titleLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                    parentLayer.addSublayer(titleLayer)
                } 
            }

            let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComp.renderSize = videoSize
            videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
            videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)


            let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: mixComposition.duration)
            instruction.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack

            let layerInstruction = self.videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: compositionVideoTrack!, asset: videoAsset)

            instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
            videoComp.instructions = [instruction]



            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
            
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(timestamp).mp4")
            SharedManager.shared.videoUrlTesting = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory).appendingPathComponent("watermarkVideo-\(timestamp).mp4")
            SharedManager.shared.instaVideoLocalPath = "watermarkVideo-\(timestamp)"

            let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter?.outputURL = url
            exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
            exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
            exporter?.videoComposition = videoComp


            exporter?.exportAsynchronously() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed {
                        let outputURL = exporter?.outputURL
                        if flag {
                            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL!.path) {
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
                                }) { saved, error in
                                    if saved {
                                        completion!(AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        } else {
                            completion!(AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed, exporter, outputURL)
                        }

                    } else {
                        // Error
                        completion!(exporter?.status, exporter, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addAudioTrack(composition: AVMutableComposition, videoAsset: AVURLAsset) {
        let compositionAudioTrack:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())!
        let audioTracks = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)
        for audioTrack in audioTracks {
            try! compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(audioTrack.timeRange, of: audioTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
        }
    }


    private func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
        var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .down
        }

        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    private func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]

        let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform: transform)

        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {
            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor),
                                     at: CMTime.zero)
        } else {
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
                let yFix = 375 + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: CGFloat(yFix))
                concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, at: CMTime.zero)

        }

        return instruction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rahul's answer seems promising but after implementing the code and using it for some days I've noticed it has some weird bugs every now and then. (no worries, sh*t happens)

I recommend this library, its extremely simple to use and provides both image and text options.

https://rubygarage.org/blog/open-source-image-and-video-processing-library-for-ios

It uses both GPU and CPU for performance optimizations as well.